# The "arrived" train

Tags: adjectives, past-participles

There is no adjective "**arrived**" in English. Only compound constructions are possible: *the recently-arrived train, the just-arrived train.* Is there an adjective/past participle which might be a legitimate one-word substitute of "**arrived**" in the incorrect phrasing *the arrived train?*

Comment: What is your context? An *arriving* train is one that is about to pull, or is now pulling into the station. An *arrived* train is one that has pulled into the station. The present participle there has widespread use, whereas the past participle appears mainly in technical documents in the railway and transportation industry.  *The driver of the arrived train must not leave the compartment until the replacement driver has arrived.*

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo I suspected that in AmEng it would be different. My source: **Oxford English Grammar Course: Advanced** by **Michael Swan and Catherine Walter** — _Some active past participles are only used in compounds, or after be. Examples: the recently-arrived train (**BUT NOT the arrived train**), a well-read woman, a much-travelled man._

Comment: This isn't an AmE versus BrE thing. I have little doubt that Swan would accept that in specialized  contexts **the arrived train** is perfectly legit. He's speaking about *everyday* contexts.

Comment: Literary uses are another possibility. Thomas Hardy, for example, uses the phrase "the traveled man".

Comment: @MvLog You haven't answered Tᴚoɯɐuo's question: what is your context?  Can you give examples of the sentences in which you would use the phrase "arrived train" if such a phrase were to be permitted?

Comment: @rjpond My context was **Oxford English Grammar Course: Advanced**, but should an example be required, I can forge a couple: _The arrived train was standing at the platform six. I rushed to the arrived train, yearning to see her as soon as possible._

Comment: I can't think of any single-word substitute.  One could perhaps call the most recently arrived train "the latest arrival". What do you mean by "arrived train" anyway?  Would this just be an abbreviated version of "the train that has just arrived" or "the (most) recently arrived train"?  Presumably all the trains at the station have arrived there at some point..

Comment: Instead of "The arrived train was standing at platform six", you could say "The train had arrived at platform six" or "The train was now standing at platform six". Otherwise I think you have to say "The newly arrived train was standing at platform six".  I think you could also get away with "The incoming train stopped at platform six" but not "The incoming train was standing at platform six".

Comment: @rjpond I'm talking about _**the** arrived train_, so, presumably, it's not just any train. Apparently, there is no single-word adjective here at least in common use. **Incoming** is not a choice—its meaning implies "being in progress".